# What kind of Open Source License is Appcelerator Titnaium using?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

We had an interesting lecture about open source projects today at work. So I went to [Titanium github repository](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile) to check what kind of license Titanium is using, but could not find a definite answer.

The closest I see there is:

> **Commercial Support, Licensing**
>
> We give our software away for FREE! In order to do that, we have programs for companies that require additional level of assistance through training or commercial support, need special licensing or want additional levels of capabilities. Please visit the Appcelerator Website for more information about Appcelerator or email info@appcelerator.com.

But that's very vague. What about commercial applications? payed applications? does a developer has to open-source his application in order to meet OSS requirements by Titanium? What about OSS that Titanium itself uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appcelerator Titanium Mobile
Copyright 2008-2013 Appcelerator, Inc.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
   You may obtain a copy of the License at

```
   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
```

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.

```
                          Apache License
                    Version 2.0, January 2004
                 http://www.apache.org/licenses/
```

See the reference https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed it :)